# UFW Firewall GUI

Tags: 15.04, ufw

Im on Ubuntu Vivid 15.04. I have UFW enable. I need some GUI to manage it.

Does anyone know or ever use UFW firewall GUI?

Comment: I think you didn't saw link in my answer...

Comment: As link-only answers aren't really considered acceptable on this site, your currently accepted answer will probably soon be deleted if it is not improved upon, so I would suggest that you accept @Raven's better answer instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run:

```
sudo apt-get install gufw
```

[image: screenshot of ufw]

For reference [help.ubuntu.com/Gufw](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Gufw)

Comment: Walla! just what i need. simple but robust.

Comment: I will, need to wait for 6 minutes before this can be accepted.

Comment: @AizuddinZali: 6 minutes are over...  The original accepted answer is really bad.  Please accept this one!